# Play n64oid saves on laptop?

Tags: windows-7, emulation, nintendo-64

Is there any way to play the game saves from n64oid on my Win7 laptop? Basically I'd like to be able to hook up my USB controller and take over from a game save I have from traveling and playing on my Android phone. Project64 seems to be incompatible with the game saves, so I tried Mupen64plus which appears to use similar save files, but it still didn't want to seem to read them. Maybe the saves would only work on linux?

The attribution in n64oid says:

> N64oid is a port of Mupen64plus along with Ari64's ARM Dynarec (and Gles2N64 as an option). The follow lists the N64oid's plugins that are based on them:
>
> - libmupen64plus-core.so
> - libmupen64plus-rsp-hle.so
> - libgles2n64.so

Curious to see if anyone has tried this and if anyone has any other ideas. I'm not horribly familiar with Mupen64plus, but I was able to get it to play the rom, it just didn't seem to like my save files. I'll try and update with the exact error if I can reproduce it.

FWIW, the game I'm playing is Zelda - Ocarina of Time and I DO have a legal copy. :)

Comment: are N64oid and Mupen64plus open source?

Comment: @TrewTzu: yes: http://sourceforge.net/projects/n64oid/ and http://code.google.com/p/mupen64plus/ I guess you're offering to write a conversion program? :-)

Comment: Are you talking about save games as in what you can use at a native N64 as well or about snapshots? The latter might be hardware specific memory dumps, while the former should indeed not vary too much, maybe in their headers if at all

Comment: @Tobias oh how i wish i had that much spare time, but when (read "if") i get some time i might look to see if they are save in the same format.

Comment: now that i think of it, @Tobias makes a good point, what files are you trying to share between the two?
a lot of PS emulators use the same format for there memory cards, maybe there is a n64 equivalent

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Good question. I am specifically talking about snapshots, but either could work.

Comment: #dtbarne I guess chances are lower there, but as @TrewTzu said, you'd need to have a look at the source code to know for sure...

Comment: Most emulators have their own savestate/snapshot format, but the save files themselves (such as the Memory Pak or whatever the N64 used) should be in the same format across different emulators.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about savestates, most likely not. The savestates emulators use are often raw dumps of the emulated memory + the emulator's state information; even among different ports of the same emulator this information could vary wildly, especially when porting between different CPUs (x86 to ARM, in this case.)

Your best bet might be to save *in game* to a Memory Pak or such a thing and then try loading *that* file on your desktop's emulator. Save files are often compatible between different emulators because they're often just a raw copy of the (S)RAM those devices contain.